# how to make my GameObjects implements my interface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

Hi I'm a little new to unity and c#. I'm trying to run a path finding algorithms between 2 nodes (GameObjects in my case), but the function pathfinding() takes interface as parameter, is to make my gameObjects implements this interface in order to be able to pass them to the function.
How can I Implement that interface in every GameObject that I have in my scene in Unity/C# , will it work if I created a script component for every GameObject that I have and make it Implement the interface as such:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour, IAStarNode
{
     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {

     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
    
     }
}
```

What if I have a large number of objects, is there a more efficient way to go?

this is the interface I want to implement:

```
public interface IAStarNode
{
    IEnumerable<IAStarNode> Neighbours
    {
        get;
    }
    float CostTo(IAStarNode neighbour);
    float EstimatedCostTo(IAStarNode goal);

}
```

Comment: When you say `gameObject`, do you mean `Component` (MonoBehaviour) ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to link the node classes (with your interface) as an exact GameObject.

Just create a new simple class without monobehaviour , and implement your interface with it.

With GameObject or Unity Scene, You could just draw UI or Graphic Expression in your game.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a script for each gameObject, you can simply create one script that Implements the interface and add it as component to all your gameObjects by selecting all of them and click on add component the select your script